# GridView to refresh when button click updates data

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have a button click event on a page which ultimate updates a table using:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AccessDataSource6.Insert();
}
```

A GridView bound to a different AccessDataSource, displays data that is updated by the Insert.

What do I need to include in Button2_Click for the GridView to be refreshed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [GridView.DataBind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx) Method will clear and re-populate your grid view (assuming the datasource is already set - see the link for an example).

Answer (score 5):

On your click event after you insert you should called the GridView.DataBind() method to rebind the data...

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AccessDataSource6.Insert();
    this.gridView1.DataBind();
}
```